# Databind multiple Lists to a grid

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I need to databind multiple Lists or BindingLists (should make no difference) to one Grid. These Lists all have the same size, but different object types. The properties of the different objects in these lists should be displayed as columns next to each other, as if the first element of list A belongs to the first element of list B and so on.

Until now I copied the data into a DataTable and used this as a datasource, but for various reasons this is not possible anymore.

I know that it's not possible to bind more than one list directly, but I have no clue how to start this. I did read a bit about databinding, but it looks like I have to code a lot for this to work, work with the CurrencyManager and so on.

Is there a simple solution that could help me? Perhaps a wrapper class that does all that?
If not, could someone give me some hints which interfaces must be implemented and what else is to keep in mind?

Comment: Clearly, what you need to do is flatten those objects and have a single list (joining the various lists as you were apparently doing with your datatable approach) and display them on the grid. What is not clear from your question is what do you refer to when you say "various reasons this is not possible anymore."? Whys is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot make these disparate objects one object, then this is not a bindable list.

You *could* do a shallow copy of each of these objects in a brand new object list and create them on-the-fly:

```
Object MyFirstObject;
Object MySecondObject;

void BindableClass( Object class_1, Object class_2 )
{
    MyFirstObject = class_1;
    MySecondObject = class_2;
}

public String _firstColumnString { get { return MyFirstObject.FirstColumnString; } }    
public String _secondColumnString { get { return MySecondObject.SecondColumnString; } }
```

Better yet, pull out just the information you need in your BindableClass constructor.

```
void BindableClass( Object class_1, Object class_2 )
{
    _firstColumnString = MyFirstObject.FirstColumnString;
    _secondColumnString = MySecondObject.SecondColumnString;
}
```

(But now you're really just down to one list again!)

You can then create the objects by doing something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TheListSize; i++)
{
     ABindableList list = new BindableClass( FirstList[i], SecondList[i] );
}
```